# Symfony CRUD generator with Bootstrap 3 support?

Tags: php, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, crud, symfony-2.3

In my job they're already using a modified Bootstrap template and it's working fine for everything in Symfony2 but I would like the CRUD's generated by Symfony2 to have Bootstrap 3 structure so it gets styled by it.

Currently I've found:

- https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle <- CRUD generation only for Bootstrap 2.0
- https://github.com/jordillonch/CrudGeneratorBundle <- only for Bootstrap 2.0
- http://knpbundles.com/MWSimple/CrudGeneratorBundle <- this seems looks OK

The problem with the bundle that "looks Ok" it's that I don't know if there's some "major vendor" bundle that provides this functionality?

Basically my question is if you know of a Bundle that produces CRUD's with Bootstrap 3 structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have to perform my own form modifications as well.  However, Symfony 2.6 introduces support for Bootstrap 3.0 for forms:

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme

So if you upgrade to Symfony 2.6 you should have that built in.

Comment: Thank you, this is great news, I will see if it's possible for us to upgrade (because bundles dependencies) and will try that feature!.

Comment: I could not upgrade Symfony 2.3 to 2.6 because other bunder in use, but I could use the templates in that pull requests, so now I know how to correctly use Bootstrap form fields in my modded template :). Thank you very much!.

Comment: "Just to expand on what I said above, this just means the html elements of forms rendered by the Symfony Forms component will be given classes from with Twitter Bootstrap. It's still up to you to include the Bootstrap CSS and Javascript on your page."

Answer (score 5):

You can try this: https://github.com/petkopara/PetkoparaCrudGeneratorBundle

It's basic CRUD generator, but have all features from the Symfony 1.4 admin generator(pagination, filtering, sorting and relations support) with **Bootstrap 3.3.6**.

Comment: Note that this is for Symfony3, if you are on LTS (2.8 currently) it may not work.

Comment: @BrianMorton Actually it's tested with 2.8 and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found this : https://github.com/developathe/crud-bundle

This CRUD's generator use **Bootstrap 3.1.1**.

Comment: Thank you, even though it's kind of unmanteined it gave me a lot of ideas to integrate it to my modded Bootstrap bundle :)

Comment: Link now 404s, so not a valid answer anymore.